# Spring Boot MockMVC test - enable pre & post annotations

Tags: spring, spring-boot, kotlin

I have a (kotlin) test that has this code with Spring Boot:

```
@Autowired
private lateinit var context: WebApplicationContext

@Autowired
private lateinit var entityManager: EntityManager

private var mockMvc: MockMvc? = null

@Autowired
lateinit var springSecurityFilterChain: Filter

@BeforeAll
fun setup() {
    mockMvc = MockMvcBuilders
        .webAppContextSetup(context)
        .addFilters<DefaultMockMvcBuilder>(springSecurityFilterChain)
        .apply<DefaultMockMvcBuilder>(springSecurity())
        .build()
}
```

This method fails with 401:

```
@PutMapping("/register")
@ResponseStatus(HttpStatus.OK)
@PreAuthorize("permitAll()")
fun registerNewUser(@Valid @RequestBody userDTO: UserDTO): User {
    val user = userDTO.toUser(passwordEncoder)
    user.activationCode = generateActivationCode()
    userRepository.save(user)
    return user
}
```

I don't understand why my pre/post authorize is not running?

I have these defined in my app's `src/main/`:

```
@Configuration
@EnableGlobalMethodSecurity(prePostEnabled = true)
class MethodSecurityConfigurer : GlobalMethodSecurityConfiguration()

@Configuration
class SecurityConfiguration {
    @Bean
    fun getPasswordEncoder(): PasswordEncoder {
        return Pbkdf2PasswordEncoder()
    }
}
```

What do I need to do in MockMVC's setup to enable the pre/post annotations?

Comment: You are using Spring Boot use `@SpringBootTest` and `@AutoconfigureMockMvc` and just autowire `MockMvc`, Spring Boot will do the setup.

Comment: Yeah, that's what I started with and it didn't work. Spring Boot does not enable the pre/post authorization methods in either case...

Comment: It should, if it doesn't there is something wrong/weird in your setup

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So I figured it out and thought I'd add the answer here.

It's not a MockMVC problem, and M. Deinum is correct in that the two annotations will work.

My issue was that `@PreAuthorize("permitAll()")` is a separate filter from the "normal" spring security filters, so I was not even getting to the method authorization aspect.

I configured Spring Security's `HttpSecurity` to allow the method, then the `permitAll()` starting working properly.

```
http.authorizeRequests().antMatchers(HttpMethod.PUT, '/register').permitAll()
```